# how can I get rid of of "./" when i run a program in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I heard I need to edit either my path in either `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

For example, instead of having to run a script or the output of a `c++ program` like `"./a.out"`, I just want to be able to type `"a.out"`?

Comment: put `.` into your $path.

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs to be in one of the paths specified in your search path.

So you if your program is located in `my_directory`:

> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:my_directory
> ```

This can be added to your `.profile / .bashrc`

It often makes sense to put your executables in standard Unix folders such as `/usr/local/bin` (already in the `$PATH`)

**Note:**

- See here for [a discussion about adding the current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come) ( `.` ) to your `$PATH`

Comment: And that's not a good idea, and opens up a hole to possibly weird things. Think about when you have a program in the current directory named the same as a system command. Today it's even considered a security hole.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg as long as . is at the end then the system command will be used. I think it's good that it's not in the path by default, but I think the risk of adding it is overblown.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so here is my .profile and my path is at the end. i just add a . at the end before the quotes?  'code' # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi